# How to get values from a GridView's templatefield textboxes in JavaScript?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, gridview, templatefield

Bear with me as I've googled this for days now and I have not been able to find one solution that works for me.  Also bear with me as I'm new to posting here but searched for many a solution!  :)

I am attempting to get some client side "agreement" when someone enters an NDA (nondisclosure agreement).  Basically what I need to do is 1) run a client side script to A) check if the value in the textbox has changed B) if the value has changed ask the user if they agree that the NDA is the right one and signed by our legal team.  Then C) save the data (in gridview) if agreed or clear out the data and not save if they do not agree.

As the name of the question suggests, the textbox is within a templatefield/editItemTemplate of a gridview.

All of this (if agreed) then goes into a database.  So basically I need a client side script to run and take input then write to a SQL database (that part I don't need help with).

Thanks,

Comment: How is this different from grabbing a value of an html element/attribute in javascript?

Comment: you can't just use the getElementByID and use the ID as there are multiple rows in a gridview and honestly using just getElementByID gives a null reference or object not found.
 I.E. document.getElementById("<%=gvCompany.ClientID%>")    works just fine, but document.getElementById("<%=txtNDA.ClientID%>") does not

Comment: Then don't use the ID? http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: well what should I use?  I'm looking for how to get this done.  I don't want to use jquery as it's nowhere in the program and I really don't know how to use it.  I'm trying to use javascript here

Comment: uh, jQuery _is_ javascript? You're saying all you want is the nth-child selector functionality from the jQuery library?

Comment: I don't even follow what you are saying as I don't know how to use jQuery, I've never used it before.....I thought I pretty clearly said what I wanted to accomplish so I'm confused by your question

Comment: That was a rhetorical question. jQuery is written in javascript. Anything that jQuery does is done via raw javascript code. It sounds like all you need to do is grab a reference to some parent of an html element and code javascript to access one of its children via basic loops and control flow.

Comment: FYI I tend to code software and I'm being asked to alter an existing website.  This is not really my strong suite and am only half familiar with javascript.  Is there a simple example you could post to help me get the ball rolling?

Comment: I think you're just going to have to accept the fact that you're probably going to have to learn some javascript to solve this problem or to just have someone else code it for you. You're better off giving coding JS a shot and asking another StackOverflow question when you get stuck. If you can code in another language, it's not all too difficult. Just open a JS console in any modern browser and type away.

Comment: I do some JS and I'm still missing the point where you give me a jumping off point......If I can easily find the gridview is there anything you can suggest to get to the textbox (templateField/EditItemTemplate) child element?  Simple code example please??  I guess another way to ask, is there any kind of JS equivalent to FindControl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best piece of code I could find was this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function Read() {
    var oDataGrid = document.getElementById("<%= GridView1.ClientID %>")
    var tableRows = oDataGrid.rows;
    var rawDataRows = new Array();
    //somewhere to put the actual data
    for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
      var thisRow = tableRows[i];
      for (var j = 0; j < thisRow.cells.length; j++) {
        alert(oDataGrid.rows(i).cells(j).innerHTML);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

basically it will iterate through all rows and all cells in rows to find exactly what you need to grab values.  I hope this helps others.

Comment: It's great that you found a solution to your problem, but there's no need to be rude about it. It appears all you needed was a way to iterate through a GridView, but wasn't apparent to me from reading your question. Lastly, I've removed my answer since it wasn't helpful to you, and I've made edits to improve the question's relevance.